# Request a client certificate through PHP for authentication

Tags: php, authentication, ssl, certificate

I'm trying to request that the browser send an installed p12 certificate for authentication programmatically.

The certificate is generated as needed by the following snippet:

```
$res = \openssl_pkey_new(Config\authentication_key_options());

\openssl_pkey_export($res, $private);
$public = \openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
$public = $pubKey["key"];

# Generate the x509 cert
$csr = \openssl_csr_new(Config\authentication_dn(), $private);
$x509 = \openssl_csr_sign($csr, null, $private, Config\AUTHENTICATION_CERT_VALID_FOR);

# Generate the pcks12
\openssl_pkcs12_export($x509, $p12, $private, null);
```

The generated certificate is then send to the client browser for download, and the private key is saved server-side for later use.

I have add the following to apache's config:

```
SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca
SSLVerifyDepth  10
SSLOptions +ExportCertData +StdEnvVars
```

When that didn't do it, I tried having my test script send a 401 header, to no avail. Adding WWW-Authenticate options as followed was equally unsuccessful:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 401");
header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic");
header("WWW-Authenticate: transport mode=\"tls-client-certificate\"");
```

So what do I have to add to programmatically (NOT statically through apache's configs) request a browser-side certificate?

Answer (score 0):

After doing more reading, it seems that it simply cannot be done.

Back to the drawing board I go

Comment: I haven't explicitly tried you setup here, but I have noticed on other threads on this subject it has been mentioned several times that there are special consideration when it comes to self-signed certificates, since the server can (always does?) send a list of acceptable CAs to the browser. If the browser doesn't contain a certificate explicitly signed by any of these CAs, the certificate is never even asked for.

Answer (score 0):

What I know is

1. The CA certificates should be loaded into JKS.
2. "SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca" this should be `SSLVerifyClient require`